# Can't Set Breakpoint On/In `if` Block in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, google-chrome-devtools

Within Chrome Dev Tools, I can set breakpoints everywhere but on, or in, an `if` block. Is that the way things work? Or should I be able to do so?

Below, I can't set a breakpoint on line 14 or 15.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to do this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndq13.png, https://output.jsbin.com/neqomak. Sometimes the devtool just get stuck especially with source-maps. Try to refresh the page, toggle the devtools or restart the browser.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's the issue. Those suggestions didn't work. Also, the same issue occurs in Firefox. This is a create-react-app and I probably need to find out where the webpack config file is so I can set the `devtool source-map` option.

Comment: Ok. How did you get to this file? If there is no source-map of the file, the browser shouldn't show you the sourced file, right?

Comment: Well, it's showing up in the browser. I'm using the default features of create-react-app and I haven't run `npm run eject`. That would give me access to the webpack config file, but I'm not sure I want to resort to that yet.

Comment: What version of create-react-app are you using?

Comment: I don't have access to it at the moment. It would have been whatever create-react-app was about a month or two ago.